# Kubuntu 14.04 webcam failure

Tags: webcam

i'm running kubuntu 14.04 on a lenovo t440s. The webcam has working perfectly until a few hours ago. This morning i also did some tests with motion and everything was going smoothly.

Now i can't find /dev/video0 anymore and cheese tells me "no device found".

please help me out with this! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it won't help much, but I have the exact same issue. The Webcam worked initially the first couple of days, then stopped. 
It still appears when I do :

```
lsusb
```

But I cannot access it. 
You can always try to test it :

```
sudo guvcview --device=/dev/video0
```

it gives be an 'inappropriate ioctl for device' error.

I did some research, and it looks like it's a frequent issue with other OS. I just assumed that the webcam is part of a faulty batch, and needs replacement.